# Java Screen with Custom JAVA_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: java, screen, java-home

I have a appilcation that needs Java 32bit on my Debian 64bit server. Is running fine now with this in the .profile or in the SH file.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_25/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/i386/server:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/local/lib
```

However, when I to start it over screen it simply don't load the Java path and the LD lib path.
Anyone has a idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please, give me the results the next commands in your console

```
java -version
```

and

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Do you have this in you environments variables?

```
env | grep JAVA
```

---

In my case I have this

```
user:$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

user:$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_25
user:$ env | grep JAVA

JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_25
```

Comment: java version "1.8.0_25"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

This is /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

    JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_25/

However, /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_25/ is 32bit.

And the Server is starting fine when i run it from the Console. (./server)
but when i do `screen -dmS Server ./server` it does not.

env | grep JAVA
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_25/